# ServiceWorker not Caching Assets

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am working on a `Progressive Web App` and I am using the `Chrome Developer Tools`. I have my `Service Worker` is installed and is activated along with the `Fetch` event. I have added the caching code in my sw.js file. When I reload the page and look in the `Cache Storage`. I do see the static-site but nothing looks cached.

**sw.js script**

```
const staticCacheName = 'site-static';
const assets = [
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/app.js',
    '/script.js',
    '/style.css',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW',
    '/images/AppliedArts.PNG',
    '/images/MasterBA.png',
    '/images/MscCS.png',
    '/images/MscEngineer.png',
    '/images/UXDesign.png'
];
// install event
self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
    //console.log('service worker installed');
    evt.waitUntil(
      caches.open(staticCacheName).then((cache) => {
        console.log('caching shell assets');
        cache.addAll(assets);
      })
    );
  });
```

[image: File Structure]

[image: Cache Storage Chrome Tools]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Have you tried [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) instead of writing your SW manually?

Comment: Not yet I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The entire setup was correct. The issue was in the urls I was including in 'assets' in the 'sw.js' file. The forward slash in front of the url was causing the issue. The best way to troubleshoot this is to eliminate all url and add 1 by 1.

```
const assets = [
    '/',
    'index.html',
    'images/AppliedArts.PNG',
    'images/MasterBA.png',
    'images/MscCS.png',
    'images/MscEngineer.png',
    'images/UXDesign.png',
    'images/logo.png',
    'style.css',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide',
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js',
    'manifest.json',
    'app.js',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    'script.js'
 
];
```